# What is this plant which closes its leaves when touched?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I came across [this video on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151746969578159&set=vb.217038473158&type=2&theater) where a plant closes its leaves when touched. Unfortunately the video does not mention the name of this plant.

**What's the name of this plant, and where can I see it?**

[image: crazy plant]

Comment: Related question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-does-the-sensitive-plant-detect-vibrations/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about plant identification. These questions are usually asked on Gardening and Landscaping Stack Exchange. This topic is not found in the following appropriate topics listing in the Help center: 1) General questions about biological concepts 2) Questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions 3) Questions about techniques in a biological or biochemical laboratory

Comment: Read some of the old, amazing works by J. C. Bose on this-plant here:http://www.gutenberg.org/files/48280/48280-h/48280-h.htm

Comment: It is quite common weed in India

Comment: It belong to family Fabaceae (pea-allied) and subfamily Mimosoideae (*Acacia*-allied). Most of the plant under this subfamily are shrubs to big trees whereas this one (*M. pudica*) is small, undershrub.

Comment: "LAAJWANTI" OR "CHOOIE MOOIE" IN HINDI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a *[Mimosa pudica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimosa_pudica)*, a wonderful plant. According to wikipedia you can find it in the following places:

> Mimosa pudica is native to South America and Central America. It has been introduced to many other regions and is regarded as an invasive species in Tanzania, South Asia and South East Asia and many Pacific Islands. It is regarded as invasive in parts of Australia and is a declared weed in the Northern Territory, and Western Australia although not naturalized there. Control is recommended in Queensland. It has also been introduced to Nigeria, Seychelles, Mauritius and East Asia but is not regarded as invasive in those places. In the United States of America, it grows in Florida, Hawaii, Virginia, Maryland, Puerto Rico, Texas, and the Virgin Islands.

If you think that's impressive, look at this video of [*Dionaea muscipula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_flytrap) the venus fly trap:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7eQKSf0LmY

Comment: Wow that is far more impressive and scary :D Looked like a horror movie.